# Firefox plugin check

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I am thinking of upgrading from firefox 3 to 3.5. However I have loads of plugins and don't know of a way to find out which are compatible, without either going to the web page of each plugin, or upgrading and seeing what breaks.

Is there a better way. Prehaps a compatibility plugin, or page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select Help > Check for Updates the dialog it launches will check all your plugins for you and show the list of the ones that aren't compatible.

You can then check that shorter list to see if there are newer versions available.

Comment: Wouldn't this be after you upgrade? at which time it would be too late for you to decide delaying the upgrade because your favorite plugin is not yet supported.

Comment: Once you upgrade, all plugins not yet compatible will anyways be disabled.

Comment: @nik - it does the check before you accept the upgrade. I'd post a screen shot, but I've recently upgraded myself.

Comment: @nik - but if you've got one you can't live without you don't want to upgrade just yet.

Comment: To clarify, this checks before you update. Letting you know what won't work and giving you a choice. Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Get the [portable firefox 3.5 edition](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable).
It will run on your system as long as you close the older version (no need to uninstall it).

You can also use the **[FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109)** and **[CLEO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2942)** extensions to package your present extensions for a quick transfer. However, I have not tested if that works across a version upgrade. Some of them will of course not install at all.

Another easy way after you setup **portable firefox 3.5** is,
If you **create** a [**collection of extensions on the firefox site**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/collections),
you can just open the **collections** page from the **3.5** and scroll over the addon list.
All unsupported addons will be identified immediately.

This collection will also be usable for installing the entire list on this version or any other firefox installation you have elsewhere.

And, this will work for all future upgrades.